# Problems receiving CSS from Media query xs chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am using the following code to render an extra small screen style, and have tested in all major supported browsers we are working with (IE 11, Chrome, Firefox, edge). The issue I am having is that on call .smallFixFooter the margin-bottom is not being applied to create a space between my stacks of divs.

CSS:

```
  @@media screen and (max-width:767){
    .smallDevices {
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .ScreenStyle {
        height: 914px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .smallFixFooter {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 text-center smallDevices smallFixFooter largeDevices">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 centerDiv footBorder smallFixFooter explorerStyleFoot" style="background-color:whitesmoke;">
        <div style="display:inline-block;width:70%" class="smallFixFooter bottomBoxFix">
            <h3><strong class="footerBoxHeader"></strong></h3>
            <p>
                <span class="explorerStyleSpan"></span>
                <audio controls id="explorerStyle" class="audioFix">
                    <source src="" type="audio/mp3" />
                </audio>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 centerDiv  footBorder smallFixFooter explorerStyleFoot" style="background-color:whitesmoke;">
        <div style="display:inline-block;width:70%" class="smallFixFooter">
            <h3><strong class="footerBoxHeader"></strong></h3>
            <p>
                <span></span><br />
                <button class="ComplianceImages" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCarousel"><img src="" /></button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 centerDiv smallFixFooter " style="background-color:whitesmoke;">
        <div style="display:inline-block;" class="bottomBoxFix">
            <h3><strong class="footerBoxHeader">foo</strong></h3>
            <p>
                <span></span>
                <button class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCertificate"><img src="" /></button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit Update: I am retrieving my sizing from this piece of jquery

```
 var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;

console.log(w,h)
```

it is telling me that the issue is that I am breaking at width 618, and that is not a standard bootstrap breakpoint.

Comment: Your media query is invalid. 767 _what_ ...?

Comment: @CBroe that is the problem, I missed defining pixels. Thank you very much.

Comment: @CBroe if you would like to put this in the form of an answer. I will upvote.

Comment: You also have @@media. Should be @meda

Comment: @Adrianopolis That is because I am using inline css in asp.net MVC, it requires the extra @ sign to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @media screen and (max-width:767){

This is an invalid media query.

Any length value in CSS always needs a unit (unless the value happens to be 0) - so make that `767px`.

<del>And as @Adrianopolis mentioned in comments, `@@media` is also incorrect, it needs to be a single @ only - `@media screen and ...`</del>

Comment: I put this in the above comments, but this is being done for ASP.Net inline css.